# Combining IF statement with array average function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, average

I am trying to get the average value of an array. If argument of the array is empty, I want the function to return null.

I have tried the following, which does not seem to work:

```
function average() {
    if ((average = [1, 2, 3])) {
        var i = 0,
        sum = 0,
        len = array.length;
                    
        while (i < len) {
            sum = sum + array[i++];
        }

        return sum / len;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

average();
console.log(average());
```

As mentioned, I want `average([])` to return null, and e.g. `average([1, 2, 3, 4])` to return 2.5.

Before I started to experiment with if, it worked fine but does not solve my problem:

```
function average() {
    array = [1, 2, 3];
    var i = 0,
    sum = 0,
    len = array.length;

    while (i < len) {
        sum = sum + array[i++];
    }
    
    return sum / len;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce would reduce your logic quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of the array.

```js
function average(array) {
  if (array.length > 0) {
    var i = 0,
      sum = 0,
      len = array.length;
    while (i < len) {
      sum = sum + array[i++];
    }
    return sum / len;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(average([1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(average([]));
```

You shouldn't assign `array` in the function, that will override the argument.